# CSS transition with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, css-transitions

I'm trying to activate a CSS transition with Javascript through DOM when a div object is clicked. I avoided jQuery and used JS on purpose in order to learn DOM (this is actually my first experiment with it).
I implemented a standard solution: getting the elements' ListNode from the HTML document, then changing the className of the desired object. Yet, it does not seem to work properly
(I'm obviously using Firefox).

Thank you in advance.

Here are the files.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel = stylesheet href = "style.css" type = "text/css" media = screen>
<script src = "script.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class = "image"  onclick = "foo()"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

> **style.css**

```
.transition {
    -moz-transition: 2s width;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;

}

.image {
    -moz-transition: 2s width;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

> **script.js**

```
function foo() {
    var k = document.getElementsByClassName("image"); 
    k[0].className = "transition";
}
```

**EDIT:** Edited the code in order to make immediately visible the working solution.

Comment: everything except the doctype should be inside the HTML element.

Comment: Stencil, look at code in your link, and look at the code you have posted. You're missing many elements.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: First of all, thank you for your accurate answer. All I'm saying is that the example on w3schools shows that <!doctype html> has to be put outside the html tag. I'm indeed missing many elements because it was only meant to be a quick experiment.

Comment: Stencil, Wouter is saying the same thing, everything except for the `<!doctype html>` element should be in the `<html>` tags, meaning the doctype should be outside of the html tags.

Comment: @Stencil Quick experiment or not... you need to stick to the correct order of elements, otherwise you can't expect things to work. As Wouter J stated, you need to put all your tags (except the doctype) within the html tag.  Within the html tag, you need a head and body tag.

Comment: Sorry, I read too fast and, consequently, I misunderstood the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `getElementsByName`, but you don't have an element with a name of `image`, instead you have an element with a class of `image`. You probably intended to use `document.getElementsByClassName('image')`. On a side note, the structure of your html page is incomplete, you need a `<head>` and `<body>` section, also your `<html>` opening tag is in the wrong place.

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
<head> 
<link rel = stylesheet href = "style.css" type = "text/css" media = screen>
<script src = "script.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <div class = "image"  onclick = "foo()"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your javascript logic:

```
function foo() {
    var k = document.getElementsByClassName("image"); 
    k[0].className = "transition";
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

As Stencil mentioned everything should be inside HTML Tag.Similar kind of width animation could be easily achieved using jQUery

```
$('.image').animate({width: 250}, 500 );
```